# Back in stock alert translation and locale Magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2.4, email-templates, stock-alert

does anyone know where the Locale of the Stock alert is located in Magento 2.4.4.?

I want to translate those strings in the e-mail:

```
In stock alert! We wanted you to know that these products are now available:

Click here to stop alerts for this product.

Unsubscribe from all stock alerts
```

The e-mail template looks like this:

```
<p class="greeting">{{trans "%name," name=$customerName}}</p>
{{var alertGrid|raw}}
```

Comment: which language would you like to translate email ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use below code in email template to translate stock alert text, it will translate according to locale by default and we can translate it using .csv files.

`<p>{{trans "In stock alert! We wanted you to know that these products are now available: Click here to stop alerts for this product. Unsubscribe from all stock alerts."}}</p>`

Comment: you can also create .html template file inside your theme and call that template file into email tempate file path like this: {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

Answer (score 0):

`alertGrid` is a rendered block content

Block: `\Magento\ProductAlert\Block\Email\Stock`

Template: `Magento_ProductAlert::email/stock.phtml`

`$_products` - list of products which back to stock

Comment: Unfortunately I am still failing to translate the same.

I have set my locale as per vendor/magento/module-inventory-product-alert/i18n but not working

Answer (score 0):

The exact strings used here are found in `Magento_ProductAlert::email/stock.phtml`

Add the translations for it in your custom theme i18n folder, in a csv file for your language code (e.g. `app/design/frontend/Your_Vendor/customtheme/i18n/nl_NL.csv` and mind case-sensitivity in language code!)

```
"In stock alert! We wanted you to know that these products are now available:","Weer in voorraad blabla"
"Click here to stop alerts for this product.","Klik om blabla"
"Unsubscribe from all stock alerts","Afmelden voor blablabla"
```

Change translations according to your desired language :)

Comment: I did so @bdbdbd. But no success.

Comment: @Ben are you in developer mode and cleared the cache and generated files? Or try `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL -f` (where nl_NL is your language code).